# How get the max value from a DataGrid field column

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

How get the max value from a dataGrid field column using Entity Framework in WPF C#

```
var MaxID = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["Id"].Value));
```

Comment: `DataGrid.Items` should be whatever data type `r` is, so cast it to an IEnumerable of those values and then check using linq. `((IEnumerable<MyItem>>)dataGrid.Items).Max(r => r.radif)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this :

```
var MaxID = (EqupmentdataGrid.Items.Cast< EntityName >()).Max(r => r.Id);
```

Ex: var MaxID = (EqupmentdataGrid.Items.Cast<'Equipment>()).Max(r => r.Id);

Result : 10002